# How do I split a string containing a numbered list into multiple strings?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I’m trying to take a string which contains a numbered list with data items next to each, and splitting these into multiple strings based on the data next to each number. I tried using regex but this caused some issues as some of the data are monetary values such as £120,000.00.

The example data is

1. `Mr Test Test`
2. `£100,000.00`
3. `5 Test Road, Test Street`

**Test Input**:

```
string testInput = "1. Mr Test Test 2. £100,000 3. 5 Test Road"
```

The numbered list may appear on separate lines in the string though, as the string is pulled from a **PDF** using `PdfTextStripper` in `PDFBox`

Is there a way I could accurately split this?

I was originally using indexof and relying on the next data item title as the stopping point, but the data is *not always the same* (`15` points on one, `25` on another).

**Desired** result is:

```
string Name = "Mr Test Test";
string Money = "£100,000.00";
string Address = "5 Test Road, Test Street";
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please include a literal input string and expected output.

Comment: Thanks Chris, added more info above.

Comment: Use a regex split with the pattern: `\s?\d+\.\s`  This will give you an array of the items at least.

Answer (score 1):

Let's implement a simple generator; we can just find line after line in a *loop*:

**Code:**

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ParseListToLines(string value) {
  int start = 0;
  bool first = true;

  for (int index = 1; ; ++index) {
    string toFind = $"{index}.";

    int next = value.IndexOf(toFind, start);

    if (next < 0) {
      yield return value.Substring(start);

      break;
    }

    if (!first) // we don't return text before the 1st item
      yield return value.Substring(start, next - start);

    first = false;
    start = next + toFind.Length;
  }
}
```

**Demo:**

```
 string testInput = "1. Mr Test Test 2. £100,000 3. 5 Test Road";

 string[] lines = ParseListToLines(testInput).ToArray();

 // string Name = lines[0].Trim();
 // string Money = lines[1].Trim();
 // string Address = lines[2].Trim();

 Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

**Outcome:**

```
 Mr Test Test
 £100,000
 5 Test Road
```

**Edit:** More Demo with *elaborated* test (new lines within and without items; one and two digits markers; text - `**` - before initial `1.` marker):

```
  // Let's build multiline string...
  string testInput = "**\r\n" + string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
    .Range(1, 12)
    .Select(i => $"{i,2}.String #{i} {(i < 3 ? "\r\n   Next Line" : "")}"));

  Console.WriteLine("Initial:");
  Console.WriteLine();

  Console.WriteLine(testInput);

  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Parsed:");
  Console.WriteLine();

  // ... and parse it into lines
  string[] lines = ParseList(testInput)
    .Select(line => line.Trim())
    .Select((item, index) => $"line number {index} = \"{item}\"")
    .ToArray();      

  Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, lines));
```

**Outcome:**

```
Initial:

**              // This text - before initial "1." marker should be ingnored
 1.String #1    // 1st item contains multiline text
   Next Line    // 1st item continuation
 2.String #2    // Again, multiline marker
   Next Line
 3.String #3 
 4.String #4 
 5.String #5 
 6.String #6 
 7.String #7 
 8.String #8 
 9.String #9 
10.String #10   // two digit markers: "10.", "11.", "12."
11.String #11 
12.String #12 

Parsed:

line number 0 = "String #1    // 1st item is multiline one
   Next Line"
line number 1 = "String #2    // 2nd item is multiline as well
   Next Line"
line number 2 = "String #3"
line number 3 = "String #4"
line number 4 = "String #5"
line number 5 = "String #6"
line number 6 = "String #7"
line number 7 = "String #8"
line number 8 = "String #9"
line number 9 = "String #10"
line number 10 = "String #11"
line number 11 = "String #12"
```

**Edit 2:** Well, let's try yet another test:

```
string testInput = 
  "1. test 5. wrong 2. It's Correct 3. OK 4. 1. 2. 3. - all wrong 5. Corect Now;";

string[] report = ParseList(testInput)
  .Select(line => line.Trim())
  .ToArray();

Console.Write(string.Join((Environment.NewLine, report));
```

**Outcome:**

```
test 5. wrong
It's Correct
OK
1. 2. 3. - all wrong
Corect Now;
```

Comment: That’s great Dmitry, thanks for that. Would it be possible to adapt the above to deal with multi line data between the numbered points? For example if the address was on multiple lines between 1. And 2. ?

Comment: @CodeTester9001: Well, let's create an *elabrated* test (see my edit)

Comment: Thanks once again. I’ll give this a go tonight and let you know how I get on

Comment: This is working great, thank you so much. One more quick question, is there a way to get it to ignore a number out of the numbered list, when there is a number before it? For example, 14. Test test 11.10 test test . I wouldn't want it to split at the 11.10 point, only the 14. if that makes sense? Thanks

Comment: @CodeTester9001: yes it make sence (see my **Edit 2**), please notice how first `5.` and second `1. 2. 3.` are *ignored*